# Could not update commit status, please check if your scan credentials belong to a member of the organization or a collaborator of the repository

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm receiving  error while running a build in Jenkins "Could not update commit status, please check if your scan credentials belong to a member of the organization or a collaborator of the repository and repo:status scope is selected"

Also I've added github user credentials to Jenkins project. Is any fix on this error.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the user you have credentials for in Jenkins has `Write` permissions or higher for the repository you are trying to build.

Comment: Is this new? It seems to have caught me out today whereas previous it worked

Comment: Been the case for as long as i've been working on Jenkins and GitHub, so at least the last few years.